# LDAP Connection TimeOut Exception

Tags: java, ldap

While debugging a LDAP connection class, if I terminate the process and do not close the LDAP connection by going into `finally block`. From next time I am not able to connect back to the LDAP directory. It throws follwoing exception for me

```
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: 1.11.1.1:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:208)
```

Is it issue from the server side or some java daemon thred?

Comment: So close the connection in the finally block. You are leaking connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue cause is server-side. Which LDAP server are you using ?

Comment: Not sure. I have got the connection details from my client. How should I address it then?

Comment: No. I don't as it's client's Active Directory.

Comment: Perhaps you should try with a standard ldap client (for example I use **apache directory studio** for eclipse which has a client, and which can launch LDAP server instance for developpement)